# Laplace Transform example

Tags: laplace-transform, poisson-process

Can someone please explain how to find the Laplace transform of $Z_t$ in the following question? I am a bit confused about how to start.

Electrical pulses with iid amplitudes $X_1, X_2,...$ arrive at a detector at random times $S_1, S_2, S_3,...$ according to a Poisson process
with rate $\lambda$. The detector output for the kth pulse at time t is:
$$\theta_k(t) = \begin{cases} 0 &t < S_k \\ 
X_k\exp(-\alpha(t-S_k)) &t \geq S_k
\end{cases}$$
This means that the amplitude measured by the detector start
with $X_k$ and then decreases exponentially at rate $\alpha$. The total
amplitude measured by the detector is then:
$$Z_t = \sum_{j=1}^N\theta_k(t)$$

Comment: Start by finding the distribution of $\sup\{k>0: S_k\leqslant t\}$.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand, why do we need to find the distribution of $S_k$? Is it not just Poisson?

Comment: The distribution of $S_k$ is Erlang with parameters $k$ and $\lambda$; not sure why you would think it was Poisson. But to compute the Laplace transform of $Z_t$, you condition on $N$, which means you need to find the distribution of $N$ - which is $\sup\{k>0:S_k\leqslant t\}$ (the number of pulses that arrive by time $t$).

Answer (score 1):

Let $F_X$ be the distribution function of $X_1$ and $N(t) = \sup\{k>0: S_k\leqslant t\}$ for $t\geqslant 0$. Let $S_0=0$. Then the distribution of the interarrival times $S_j-S_{j-1}$ is exponential with parameter $\lambda$ so the distribution of the arrival times $S_k = \sum_{j=1}^k (S_j-S_{j-1})$ is Erlang with parameters $\lambda$, $k$ - that is, $F_k(t):=\mathbb P(S_k\leqslant t) = \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda t}$.  Now, for each $t\geqslant 0$ and nonnegative integer $k$, we have the equivalence $\{N(t) = k\}=\{S_k\leqslant t<S_{k+1}\}$. It follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(N(t) = n) &= F_n(t) - F_{n+1}(t)\\
&= \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda t} - \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda t}\\
&= \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda t},
\end{align}
that is, $N(t)$ has Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda t$.

We now compute the Laplace transform of $Z_t$:
\begin{align}
\mathcal L\{Z_t\} &= \mathbb E[e^{-sZ_t}]\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb E\left[e^{-sZ_t}\mid N(t)=k\right]\mathbb P(N(t)=k)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb E\left[e^{-s \sum_{j=1}^k X_je^{-\alpha(t-S_j)}}\mid N(t)=k\right] \frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda t}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda t}\prod_{j=1}^k \mathbb E\left[ e^{-sX_j e^{-\alpha(t-S_j)} } \right] \\
\end{align}
From here I am unsure how to proceed, since the distribution of $X_1$ is not given.